# How to access value of a different variable on relational table with foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata

Assume that ı have two tables in my DB. I want to access a different variable of my second table that is mapped to a foreign key from a variable of the main table.Is this possible that reach an another variable's value from LookUp table in model. I google it but never reached a solution.

I want to ask that how the model can do this automatically? and these are my tables model;

A: id:1, LookUpID:1;

LookUp: id:2, name: "some name"

The result will look like;

{
   A:{
       id: 1,
       LookUp: "some name"
     }
}

excuse my english, thank you in advance.

```
[Table("A")]
public class A
{
   [Key]
   public int id {get; set;}
   [Column("LookUp")]
   public int LookUpID {get; set;}

   [ForeignKey="LookUpID"]
   public virtual LookUp lookup {get; set;}
}

public class LookUp
{
   [Key]
   public int id {get; set;}
   public string name {get; set;}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to access LookUp name on your model A that you just retrieved from the database ? 
Just include that property navigation on your query like so :

```
var aModelFromDb = await dbContext.A.Include(a => a.lookup).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

now your A model can access it's LookUp object like so:

```
var lookupName = aModelFromDb.Lookup.name
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like projection is what you're after. To return an object with an ID and a Lookup's name:

```
public class AViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Lookup { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
var models = context.As.Select(a => new AModel { Id = a.Id, Lookup = a.Lookup.Name }).ToList();
```

This can be serialized to JSON to look like:

```
{ Id: 1, Lookup: "test message" }
```

If you just want to process the details locally without returning the data outside of the function for instance, you can project to an anonymous type:

```
var models = context.As.Select(a => new { Id = a.Id, Lookup = a.Lookup.Name }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand  and will try it.